FA-Ads : Disabling data collection. Found google_app_id in strings.xml but Google Analytics for Firebase is missing
I have a strange issue in my android application where I try to adding AdMob advertising based on Firebase connection:

W FA-Ads  : Disabling data collection. Found google_app_id in strings.xml but Google Analytics for Firebase is missing. Remove this value or add Google Analytics for Firebase to resume data collection.

I'm sure that my Firebase project created with enabled Google Analytics, also I see in Firebase that Analytics is enabled for my project.
I'm sure that my application has connection to Firebase, if I delete FB config from application I will receive another error - there are no Firebase connection.
More over I can see advertising in my Nativescript application with developer AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/9214589741"
Error message
Problem only with this error about error with disabled Google Analytics. Of course with real AdMob ID nothing will be working, if Google Analytics disabled.
So, how to turn on Google Analytics and force it enabled in Android application?
